# Uninteded datatype change when converting Spark dataframe to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I'm working on a project which has a specific code where a spark dataframe is converted to a pandas dataframe, provided below.

```
df = spark.sql("select * from dbo.table1")
df_pd = df.select("*").toPandas()
```

However, when I check the schema of spark and the pandas dataframe, all `decimal(38,18)` columns have been converted to `object` type, except two columns which were converted to `float64`. This is causing issues further down the code where aggregation happens since there's no numeric type to aggregate.
Can someone explain why this happens and suggest a workaround?

Comment: can you please share your data format

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj I can't share the data since its an enterprise project. But I can provide more info if you can say what exactly you are looking for

Comment: data format . is it either delta or parquet or csv ?

Comment: Having the same issue, also cant share my data